# Python: optimizing the product of a chain of factor-to-the-nth if n is not zero

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a pythonic, descriptive way to multiply a list of numbers, raised to a corresponding number so long as the number is not zero. Here is a simple version of what I am doing, where I hard-coded a list of factors as [2, 3, 5]:

```
>>> import operator
>>> ## numbers could be written as lambda factor_list, power_list: [[factor_list[i]...
>>> numbers = lambda x, y, z: [[2, 3, 5][i] ** [x, y, z][i] for i in xrange(3)
        if [x, y, z][i] != 0]
>>> product = lambda numbers: reduce(operator.mul, numbers, 1)
>>> numbers(1, 0, 0)
[2]
>>> product(numbers(1, 0, 0))
2
>>> numbers(1, 2, 3)
[2, 9, 125]
>>> product(numbers(1, 2, 3))
2250
```

I could have written this as a function with a for-loop which simply avoids any additional multiplication if the power value equals 0; e.g. `if n !=0: product *= f ** n` and loop as needed. I feel list comprehensions and lambda are there as a potentially better alternative.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: And do you have a reason to go out of your way to avoid that multiplication? Chances are it doesn't make a measurable difference, or even makes it slower because of the extra check and branching.

Comment: @Jon There are many ways to code this, I wanted to post mine and see if I was missing a quality of python which would be .. well .. more pythonic. I find each time I figure out one of those, my coding gets a lot better.

Comment: Might be more suited to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com then...

Comment: @delnan It's not that I want to avoid multiplication, It's just that I find `reduce(operator.mul, list)` very easy to read, and I don't know a way to calculate the product of a list of numbers which scans better (or writes out as a shorter, but still descriptive line of code).

Comment: @Jon @elyase provides a great answer, which shows the use of `zip` which is not a function I use too often. It's also a concept which applies broadly. It's the type of answer which I find very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pythonic enough:

```
>>> from operator import mul

>>> base = [2, 3, 5]
>>> powers = [1, 0, 0]
>>> l = [n**p for n, p in zip(base, powers) if p != 0]
[2]
>>> reduce(mul, l, 1)
2
```

With generators:

```
>>> from itertools import izip

>>> powers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> numbers = (n**p for n, p in izip(base, powers) if p != 0)
>>> reduce(mul, numbers , 1)
2250
```